# Adding an item to Room Database at specific time every day

Tags: java, android, android-studio, scheduled-tasks, android-room

I need code to add item to `Room Database` at 12 AM every day. I have tried many ways such as `WorkManager` and `AlarmManager` but they don't achieve this target

Comment: When your app is open, just make a timer of some kind. When user closes the app, save the time in shared prefs. When user opens the app, add missing items using the close time as a reference.

Comment: can you give me more details please

Comment: Do you use Room?

Comment: Yes i use room!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation of what I mentioned in my comment:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String PREF_PAUSE_TIME_KEY = "exit_time";

    private static final Long MILLIS_IN_DAY = 86400000L;

    private static final int TRIGGER_HOUR = 12;
    private static final int TRIGGER_MIN = 0;
    private static final int TRIGGER_SEC = 0;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    private final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    private final Runnable addItemRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(addItemRunnable, MILLIS_IN_DAY);
            addItem();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //...

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Add missing events since onPause.
        long resumeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long pauseTime = prefs.getLong(PREF_PAUSE_TIME_KEY, resumeTime);

        // Set calendar to trigger time on the day the app was paused.
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(pauseTime);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, TRIGGER_HOUR);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, TRIGGER_MIN);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, TRIGGER_SEC);

        long time;
        while (true) {
            // If calendar time is during the time that app was on pause, add item.
            time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            if (time > resumeTime) {
                // Past current time, all items were added.
                break;
            } else if (time >= pauseTime) {
                // This time happened when app was on pause, add item.
                addItem();
            }

            // Set calendar time to same hour on next day.
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        // Set handler to add item on trigger time.
        handler.postDelayed(addItemRunnable, time - resumeTime);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Save pause time so items can be added on resume.
        prefs.edit().putLong(PREF_PAUSE_TIME_KEY, System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();

        // Cancel handler callback to add item.
        handler.removeCallbacks(addItemRunnable);
    }

    private void addItem() {
        // Add item to database and RecyclerView.
    }
}
```

- When `onPause` is called, the current time is saved in the preferences.
- When `onResume` is called, the program add every item that should have been added while the app wasn't opened.
- When the app is opened the program uses a `Handler` to post a task at a specific time.

You can move the code anywhere you want, most likely in your repository or view model if you have one. For the timer you can use RxJava for the in-app timer or anything else really.

If the user changes the time to a few days earlier, added items won't be removed. If user then sets it back to normal, items for some days will be duplicated. You can prevent this by only saving the time in `onPause` if it's greater than the last saved time.

Comment: What's not working? Can you try adding log statements or breakpoints to see what is called and what isn't. It worked when I tested it a month ago.

Comment: but there is problem when `onPause` all items disappears @Nicolas

Comment: From where? The database, or your list? The problem must be in your code, there's no logic in the code I gave you to even add items.

Comment: in my list help me please

Comment: Are the items in your Room database? If not they sure will be deleted when the app exits. If yes, then just query your database to display the items. I can't really tell why they're disappearing without seeing your code. Post a new question.

Comment: here is my question go and take a look i hope you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61413871/items-in-recyclerview-disappeared-onpause-of-activity @Nicolas