# items in RecyclerView disappeared OnPause of Activity

Tags: java, android, android-room

my app add item to `Recyclerview` at 12 AM it added then it disappears when `OnPause` of activity here is my code & i don't know if it deleted from my `RoomDatabase` or from my `RecyclerView`

**ListOfItemsActivity.java**

```
RecyclerView notesRecyclerView;
NotesRecyclerViewAdapter notesRecyclerViewAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
NotesViewModel notesViewModel;
List<Note> note = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String PREF_PAUSE_TIME_KEY = "exit_time";

private static final Long MILLIS_IN_DAY = 86400000L;

private static final int TRIGGER_HOUR = 0;
private static final int TRIGGER_MIN = 0;
private static final int TRIGGER_SEC = 0;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private SharedPreferences prefs;

private final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

private final Runnable addItemRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(addItemRunnable, MILLIS_IN_DAY);
        addNote();
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recorded_notes);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.e("state","onResumeStarted");

    // Add missing events since onPause.
    long resumeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long pauseTime = prefs.getLong(PREF_PAUSE_TIME_KEY, resumeTime);

    // Set calendar to trigger time on the day the app was paused.
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(pauseTime);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, TRIGGER_HOUR);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, TRIGGER_MIN);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, TRIGGER_SEC);

    long time;
    while (true) {
        // If calendar time is during the time that app was on pause, add item.
        time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        if (time > resumeTime) {
            // Past current time, all items were added.
            addNote();
            break;
        } else if (time >= pauseTime) {
            // This time happened when app was on pause, add item.
            fillingRecyclerView();
        }

        // Set calendar time to same hour on next day.
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    // Set handler to add item on trigger time.
    handler.postDelayed(addItemRunnable, time - resumeTime);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e("state","onPauseStarted");

    // Save pause time so items can be added on resume.
    prefs.edit().putLong(PREF_PAUSE_TIME_KEY, System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();

    // Cancel handler callback to add item.
    handler.removeCallbacks(addItemRunnable);
}


public void addNote(){

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E", new Locale("ar"));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", new Locale("ar"));
    final Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String[] states = new String[6];
    MainSharedPrefes mainSharedPrefes = new MainSharedPrefes(this);
    if (mainSharedPrefes.getMorningState()){

        states[0] = "+";

    }else {

        states[0] = "-";

    }
    if(mainSharedPrefes.getEveningState()){

        states[1] = "+";

    }else {

        states[1] = "-";

    }
    if (mainSharedPrefes.getNightState()){

        states[2] = "+";

    }else {

        states[2] = "-";

    }
    if (mainSharedPrefes.getEchauristState()){

        states[3] = "+";

    }else {

        states[3] = "-";

    }
    if (mainSharedPrefes.getConfessState()){

        states[4] = "+";

    }else {

        states[4] = "-";

    }
    if (mainSharedPrefes.getBibleState()){

        states[5] = "+";

    }else {

        states[5] = "-";

    }
    note.add(new Note(sdf.format(timestamp),sdf2.format(timestamp),states[0],states[1],states[2],states[3],states[4],states[4],mainSharedPrefes.getWritedNotes()));



}



public void fillingRecyclerView(){

    notesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotesViewModel.class);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
    notesRecyclerViewAdapter = new NotesRecyclerViewAdapter(note);
    notesRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.notesRecyclerView);
    notesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    notesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    notesRecyclerView.setAdapter(notesRecyclerViewAdapter);


}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
private List<Note> notesList = new ArrayList<>();

NotesRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Note> notesList) {
    this.notesList = notesList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NotesRecyclerViewAdapter.NotesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note, parent, false);
    return new NotesViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NotesRecyclerViewAdapter.NotesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Note currentNote = notesList.get(position);
    holder.day.setText(currentNote.getDay());
    holder.date.setText(currentNote.getDate());
    holder.morningState.setText(currentNote.getMorningState());
    holder.eveningState.setText(currentNote.getEveningState());
    holder.nightState.setText(currentNote.getNightState());
    holder.echuaristState.setText(currentNote.getEucharistState());
    holder.confessState.setText(currentNote.getConfessState());
    holder.bibleState.setText(currentNote.getBibleState());
    holder.notes.setText(currentNote.getNotes());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notesList.size();
}

class NotesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView date;
    TextView day;
    TextView morningState;
    TextView eveningState;
    TextView nightState;
    TextView echuaristState;
    TextView confessState;
    TextView bibleState;
    TextView notes;

    NotesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        date           = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateInNote);
        day            = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayInNote);
        morningState   = itemView.findViewById(R.id.morningState);
        eveningState   = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eveningState);
        nightState     = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nightState);
        echuaristState = itemView.findViewById(R.id.echuaristState);
        confessState   = itemView.findViewById(R.id.confessState);
        bibleState     = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bibleState);
        notes          = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesInRecordedNotes);

    }
}
```

**AppDatabase.java**

```
@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class NotesDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static NotesDatabase instance;
public abstract Dao dao();
public static synchronized NotesDatabase getInstance(Context context){

    if(instance == null){

        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), NotesDatabase.class, "notes_database").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();

    }

    return instance;

}
private static RoomDatabase.Callback callback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
    }

};

private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private Dao dao;

    public PopulateDbAsyncTask(NotesDatabase database) {

        dao = database.dao();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

i hope anyone helps me

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug this without knowing almost any relevant information, like your adapter code, Room code, which item is missing, how it's added to the database...

Comment: done added more information @RyanM

Comment: Among other problems: `PopulateDbAsyncTask` doesn't do anything, but you never call it anyway.  In fact, none of your code uses the database at all.  You're also never using the `adapter.notify...` methods to tell the `RecyclerView` the data changed.  I suspect that last one is your immediate problem.